# How to deploy directories to test output folders in Visual Studio 2008 Team System?

Tags: visual-studio, mstest, testrunconfig

When open my LocalTestRun.testrunconfig file Deployment section I can choose which files are deployed to the Test output folders, but I need that a specific file to be deployed in a given subfolder. How to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify subdirectories for files or directories using the `outputDirectory` attribute of the `DeploymentItem` element:

```
<TestRunConfiguration ...>
...
  <Deployment>
    <DeploymentItem filename="%File or Directory to deploy path%" 
                    outputDirectory="%output subdirectory%" />
```

- `filename` attribute can contain absolute paths or relative paths(to the RelativePathRoot which is the directory of the solution containing your test project)
- if you want to deploy a directory, all files in that directory will be copied to the destination subdirectory but not the directory itself, i.e.:
   will copy files from Dir1 directly under Dir2, no directory 'Dir1' will be creaed under Dir2 to contain these files.
- `outputDirectory` attribute contains destination subdirectory under the deployment root directory

O_o

Comment: In VS2010, you'll need to refresh your TestView window to get the update .testconfig file to load properly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, where integration tests where dependent on files being in a specific folder. I ended up adding a script to the post build event of one of my projects to copy in the files to the right location using xcopy.